# Cartographer level keeps resetting back to Stone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a cartography table that has a cartographer next to it in my village. He trades an emerald for 24 paper, so I have two auto sugar cane farms running in the background while I go afk. I traded enough so he gained the second set of trade options, but when I came back from afk he was reset to only the first two. Other villagers, like the farmer, remained at an advanced level but not the cartographer.

Is this a bug, or a feature of the cartographer to prevent the player from spamming to get the globe banner pattern?

This is on Java edition v.1.15

Comment: Are you sure that it's the same villager and not just another one that looks similar? In other words, do the villagers run around freely? Also, in which version do you create that world?

Comment: I'm sure. I do raise my villagers free-range, but I triple checked if there was another cartographer, and it was the only one. I created the world yesterday, so in 1.15.

Comment: Then that sounds like a bug. If you can reproduce it reliably, search for a report and if there isn't one, report it.

Comment: The only way to *know* is to name the villager using a name tag.  It is entirely possible that your villager died, a new one was "born" and took the only available workstation....